# How do I open a new sql pane in DataGrip?

Tags: datagrip

[image]This is a question I am going to answer myself. I Simply need to know how to open another sql pane in DataGrip. I have one pane open and would like to have at least two to work off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are like me you are used to the phrase sql pane. Datagrip calls these consoles. So to open a new "sql pane" you need to open a new console. This is done by doing the following. [image: open console] and a new pane will appear.

Comment: In 2017.3 we are introducing Jump To Console action in context menu which will allow you to jump to any of existing consoles: https://d3nmt5vlzunoa1.cloudfront.net/datagrip/files/2017/09/EAP_JumpToConsole.png